# Failed to boot Win 7 from external HDD on modified Chromebook

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, usb

The HDD has Windows 7 on it and I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on a Parrot Chromebook with SeaBIOS.

I got the internal hard drive from an old Toshiba laptop and put it in a caddy so I can use it as an external drive. I would like to boot *and **run*** Windows 7 from the external hard drive.

However, when I select the hard drive to boot from, it boots Ubuntu. I think this is because ***it*** (the hard drive) looks for a local bootable operating system before it looks for an external OS.

The HD caddy converts SATA to USB 3.0 and plugs into my computer with a standard USB male end.

I have two questions and they are these:

1. **Which** files do I edit to have Windows' boot loader (I guess that's what it is), on the hard drive, boot USB by default, specifically, itself?
2. What do I **modify** in the file(s) to achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you want to run it as [Windows-to-go](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go)?

Comment: Are you sure you selected it? In some BIOS, you need to press space before pressing Enter in order to select and confirm your choice.

Comment: Is your BIOS the version that you select by pressing a number? or the type where you navigate the boot devices using arrow keys

Comment: @varfirstName Yes, I'm sure I selected it. I've been having fun "trying" many different operating systems from USBs. I'm using SeaBIOS. I had to replace Chrome's custom BIOS to boot/install any other operating system. Yes, I select it by pressing 2. 1 is the local hard drive with Ubuntu, 2-whatever is anything is a USB port, and the last one is Jeltka, installing from payload.

Comment: @Biswa I would like to but I'm not sure if that's possible as it's Windows 7.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing.  Please edit the question with the most relevant info first : You have a Chromebook with Ubuntu 1704 installed.  You have an old HD you have put into a portable case with USB (I think, it's vague in the question).  Your Chromebook won't boot from the USB HD.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I have improved the question format and added other important information, I think. Thank you for the comment.